# How can I efficiently get all divisors of X within a range if I have X's prime factorization?

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, primes, prime-factoring

So I have algorithms (easily searchable on the net) for prime factorization and divisor acquisition but I don't know how to scale it to finding those divisors within a range. For example all divisors of 100 between 23 and 49 (arbitrary). But also something efficient so I can scale this to big numbers in larger ranges. At first I was thinking of using an array that's the size of the range and then use all the primes <= the upper bound to sieve all the elements in that array to return an eventual list of divisors, but for large ranges this would be too memory intensive.

Is there a simple way to just directly generate the divisors?

Answer (score 2):

Let `n[i]` be the i-th factor of your number `x`, `i` < `m`.  For any integer `j` greater than 1 and less than `2^m`, then the product of all `n[j[r]]` where `j[r]` is the `r-th` bit of `j` is a divisor of `x`.

Consider 105.  Its factors are `[3, 5, 7]`.  So 3 factor, 2^3 is 8:

```
 0  000                = 1
 1  001              7 = 7
 2  010          5     = 5
 3  011          5 * 7 = 35
 4  100      3         = 3
 5  101      3   *   7 = 21
 6  110      3 * 5     = 15
 7  111      3 * 5 * 7 = 105
```

See?  All possible divisors of 105 (0 and 7 are a little questionable).

Comment: Would you be able to explain this using an example?

Comment: Note also that you do explicitly need duplicate factors.  If you're getting the unique prime divisors (3,5) for 45, instead of (3,3,5) it wouldn't give you 9 as a possible divisor.

Comment: I am trying to find only the divisors within a range, though -- I already have methods for finding all divisors in general

Comment: The generation of duplicates for numbers which have some prime multiple times in their factorization is not very elegant. Also 3*7=21. This probably would be done better using recursion and a loop for the multiplicities of the primes.

Comment: Order the divisors from highest to lowest.  Do what Malvolio suggested, but use a modified binary search to find the lowest number  that generates an invalid value.   Ditto the highest number that generates an invalid value.  Anything greater or less than that can be ignored.   Anything in the remaining range can be generated and checked

Comment: Are we talking about different things, here? Do I need to clarify my question?

Comment: @James: Binary search won't work -- this mapping is not monotonic.

Comment: It's easier to generate *all* the divisors and discard the duplicates and those out of range than try to only generate certain ones.

Comment: @Malvolio: Conceptually easier, yes.  Computationally faster, if you have a thousand prime factors, maybe not.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out my own question. How do I close this?

Comment: I think you can delete it

Comment: @BenVoigt -- I believe the problem is equivalent to a knapsack problem.  If so, it's NP-complete and cannot be solved in polynomial-time.

Comment: @KaliMa: The best thing to do is submit an answer to your own question.  Then accept it using the checkmark.  That helps future visitors with similar problems.

Comment: @James -- for this system, you would write the divisors of 45 as (3,3,5), and post-process to eliminate dups.

Answer (score 0):

As Malvolio was (indirectly) going about, I personal wouldn't find a use for prime factorization if you want to find factors in a range, I would start at int t = (int)(sqrt(n)) and then decremnt until
1. t is a factor
2. Complete util t or t/n range has been REACHED(a flag) and then (both) has left the range

Or if your range is relatively small, check versus those values themselves.

Comment: Well, unless the number is really big (like, say, 2^32 * 3^32). Then I doubt you will want to use this approach.

Comment: Yeah, far easier to generate all 1089 numbers of the form `2^m * 3^n` where `n` and `m` are less than or equal to 32.  In Python: `[ 2**n * 3**m for m in range(33) for n in range(33) ]`

Answer (score -1):

If you know the factors of *n*, you can calculate the divisors of *n* --- those numbers, including 1 and *n*, that evenly divide *n* --- by taking the products of the powerset of the factors of *n*:

```
function divisors(n)
    divs := [1]
    for fact in factors(n)
        temp := []
        for div in divs
            if fact * div not in divs
                append fact * div to temp
        divs := divs + temp
    return divs
```

Once you have the complete list of divisors, you can select only those that are in the required range.

Comment: Generating the complete list of divisors is what the OP is explicitly trying to avoid.